# 2 RDP session on windows server with azure

Tags: windows, azure, rdp, cal

I want to setup a windows server computer.

I have the same problem on all windows server editions since 10 years: If 2 users try to connect with RDP, the first user is disconnected.

What i want to do is to allow 2 users at the same time.

I have read i need to buy cals for my server.

But i want to create a virtual machine on azure portal. Is there a way to do this on azure ? Or should i buy CAL directly to a Microsoft Reseller ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use different users for each person logging in.

Comment: I do not need CAL licences ?

Comment: No you don't as long as we are only talking about one user requiring two concurrent sessions

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please don't forget to upvote and/or accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registry try changing the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ TerminalServer\fSingleSessionPerUser` from `1` to `0`. If that key doesn't exist add a new DWORD accordingly.